# How to draw an arrow in a diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I found the code for

[image]

I tried to put an arrow at the end points to join 0 to 0 but I couldn't. Any help?

Edited: Here is the code I found

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
    column sep=3em]
    { 0 & A  & B  & C  & 0 \\
      0 & A' & B' & C' & 0 \\ };
  { [start chain] \chainin (m-1-1);
    \chainin (m-1-2);
    { [start branch=A] \chainin (m-2-2)
        [join={node[right] {$\scriptstyle\eta_1$}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-3) [join={node[above]
                      {$\scriptstyle\varphi$}}];
    { [start branch=B] \chainin (m-2-3)
        [join={node[right] {$\scriptstyle\eta_2$}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-4) [join={node[above]
                      {$\scriptstyle\psi$}}];
    { [start branch=C] \chainin (m-2-4)
        [join={node[right] {$\scriptstyle\eta_3$}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-5); }
  { [start chain] \chainin (m-2-1);
    \chainin (m-2-2);
    \chainin (m-2-3) [join={node[above]
                      {$\scriptstyle\varphi'$}}];
    \chainin (m-2-4) [join={node[above]
                      {$\scriptstyle\psi'$}}];
    \chainin (m-2-5); }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please include an example in your question rather than an external link. Include the link as the source, of course, to attribute the code.

Comment: that sort of diagram is much easier with `tikz-cd`

Comment: Try adding a `\chainin (m-2-5);` between `\chainin (m-1-5);` and `}`

Comment: @AJN: Yes it works what about the left side?

Comment: The `(m-1-5)` and `(m-2-5)` refer to the nodes in the matrix in rows 1 and 2, respectively, and column 5. So for the left hand arrow you need `(m-1-1)` and `(m-2-1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not use `\chainin` at all and would instead use `\draw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=10mm,column sep=16mm]{
        0 & A  & B  & C  & 0 \\
        0 & A' & B' & C' & 0 \\
     };
     \foreach \a [evaluate={\b=int(\a+1)}] in {1,4} {
       \draw[->](M-1-\a)--(M-1-\b);
       \draw[->](M-2-\a)--(M-2-\b);
     }
     \foreach \a [count=\b] in {2,3,4} {\draw[->](M-1-\a)--node[right]{$\eta_\b$}(M-2-\a);}
     \draw[->](M-1-2)--node[above]{$\varphi$}(M-1-3);
     \draw[->](M-2-2)--node[above]{$\varphi'$}(M-2-3);
     \draw[->](M-1-3)--node[above]{$\psi$}(M-1-4);
     \draw[->](M-2-3)--node[above]{$\psi'$}(M-2-4);
     \draw[->](M-1-1)--(M-2-1);
     \draw[->](M-1-5)--(M-2-5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is much simpler and produces:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For completeness (and IMO, because the code is simpler) here is another way to do this in tikz (I didn't change the phi's)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  0 \arrow{r} \arrow{d} &  A \arrow{r}{\phi} \arrow{d}{\eta_1}
  & B \arrow{r}{\psi} \arrow{d}{\eta_2}
  & C \arrow{r} \arrow{d}{\eta_3} 
  & 0 \arrow{d}
  \\
  0 \arrow{r} & A' \arrow{r}{\phi'} & B' \arrow{r}{\psi'} 
  & C' \arrow{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]